# Wpf Textbox Cursor on mouse hover

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor

I have a window within my app, this is a small window, but 80% of it is textbox.
The annoyance I am having is that when I hover my mouse over the textbox, the cursor remains as an arrow, and I want to set an IBeam.

I have tried:

- setting *Property="Cursor" Value="IBeam"* in the ResourceDictionary (Style & Style.Triggers)
- setting *Cursor="IBeam"* explicitly in the window xaml.

I have noticed that if I click the mouse within the textbox, then I see the expected cursor, but nothing will make the hover work.

Is there any other way I can try to set the cursor?

** Edit **
My Textbox has an adorner layer associated to it (I do have IsHitTestVisible = false set for that)

Comment: Have you tried setting the Cursor property in the adorner?

Comment: In the Adorner I have set *Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.IBeam;* but this makes no difference either

Comment: Hmm. I'll have to be the designated "show us your code" person on this one. There's got to be something subtle in the implementation that's causing it. Maybe you can put a minimal example on Github?

Comment: from what I can see it is not code related as I added a basic Textbox <Textbox Cursor="IBeam" /> and I see the same behaviours.

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't even need the `Cursor=` for a normal `TextBox`. `TextBox` must have been globally retemplated somewhere - are you using a 3rd party control library / theme? This may be a longshot, but if the control has been retemplated such that none of the layers has a non-`null` background (i.e. something has to at least be `"Transparent"`), that could defeat `Cursor` because WPF won't think you're over the control. It'd almost be like `HitTestVisible="False"` You could test this by seeing if you get the ibeam as you cross the border of the box, or just giving the box a background color.

Comment: Why don't you show the code of the TextBox , the adorner and how you set things up? Right now this is a quiz show. Please post something meaningful for a code review. Something that reproduces the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `OnMouseEnter` of the textbox event and set the cursor to an IBeam and then reset the cursor to an arrow via `OnMouseleave` event.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Sadly I have tried this and still always see the arrow.
The only change I do see is that when I click in the textbox, the cursor changes, but just on hover it is always the arrow.

Comment: Good idea to try it though.